# Using PrettyTable to print out details of Python files in directory

Tags: python, function, class, oop, prettytable

I'm attempting to write a FileAnalyzer class that would search a directory for Python files and provide details of each Python file in the form of a PrettyTable. I'm interested in the number of classes, functions, lines, and characters in each Python file.

Learning the ropes of OOP...here's the code I have so far:

```
class FileAnalyzer:
    def __init__(self, directory: str) -> None:
        """
        The files_summary attribute stores the summarized data for each Python file in the specified directory.
        """
        self.directory: str = os.listdir(directory) #Directory to be scanned

        self.analyze_files()  # summarize the python files data

        self.files_summary: Dict[str, Dict[str, int]] = {
            dir: {
                'Number of Classes': cls,
                'Number of Functions': funccount,
                'Number of Lines of Code': codelines,
                'Number of Characters': characters
            }
        }

    def analyze_files(self) -> None:
        """
        This method scans a directory for python files. For every python file, it determines the number of classes,
        functions, lines of code, and characters. The count for each one is returned in a tuple.
        """
        for dir in self.directory:
            if dir.endswith('.py'):  # Check for python files
                with open(dir, "r") as pyfile:

                    cls = 0  # Initialize classes count
                    for line in pyfile:
                        if line.startswith('Class'):
                            cls += 1

                    funccount = 0  # Initialize function count
                    for line in pyfile:
                        if line.startswith('def'):
                            funccount += 1

                    #Get number of lines of code
                    i = -1 #Account for empty files
                    for i, line in enumerate(pyfile):
                        pass

                    codelines = i + 1

                    #Get number of characters
                    characters = 0
                    characters += sum(len(line) for line in pyfile)

        return [cls, funccount, codelines, characters]


    def pretty_print(self) -> None:
        """
        This method creates a table with the desired counts from the Python files using the PrettyTable module.
        """
        pt: PrettyTable = PrettyTable(field_names=['# of Classes', '# of Functions', '# Lines of Code (Excluding Comments)',
                                                   '# of characters in file (Including Comments)'])

        for cls, funccount, codelines, characters in self.files_summary():
            pt.add_row([cls, funccount, codelines, characters])

        print(pt)

FileAnalyzer('/path/to/directory/withpythonfiles')
```

Currently getting an error of `NameError: name 'cls' is not defined` when I try to run the code. Is calling `self.analyze_files()` within `__init__` not enough to pass the returned values into `__init__`? Ideally, for a python file of

```
def func1():
    pass

def func2():
    pass

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The PrettyTable would tell me that there are 2 classes, 4 functions, 25 lines, and 270 characters. For a file of:

```
definitely not function

This is def not a function def
```

The PrettyTable would tell me that the file has 0 functions. I would like `self.analyze_files()` to populate summarized data into `self.files_summary` without passing any other arguments to `analyze_files()`. And likewise passing the data from `files_summary` to `pretty_print` without a separate argument passed to `pretty_print`.

Edit:

```
self.files_summary: Dict[str, Dict[str, int]] = {
            dir: {
                'Number of Classes': self.analyze_files()[0],
                'Number of Functions': self.analyze_files()[1],
                'Number of Lines of Code': self.analyze_files()[2],
                'Number of Characters': self.analyze_files()[3]
            }
        }
```

suppressed the errors, but

```
        for self.analyze_files()[0], self.analyze_files()[1], self.analyze_files()[2], self.analyze_files()[3] in self.files_summary():
            pt.add_row([self.analyze_files()[0], self.analyze_files()[1], self.analyze_files()[2], self.analyze_files()[3]])

        return pt
```

in `pretty_print` doesn't do anything when I call FileAnalyzer...

Comment: You are setting `'Number of Classes': cls,` in your `__init__` function, but there is no variable named `cls` defined in that function. You'll have the same error with the other variables mentioned in that same block.

Comment: @larsks Right, so I suppose my question is can I reference the `cls` I've already defined in `analyze_files` without requiring additional arguments in `analyze_files`. If I do something like `[cls, funccount, codelines, characters] = self.analyze_files()` within `__init__`, doesn't seem to reference the returned values properly either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a bit broad, so it's hard to provide a concise answer.  You said in comments:

> If I do something like `[cls, funccount, codelines, characters] = self.analyze_files()` within **init**, doesn't seem to reference the returned values properly either

While a little odd stylistically, that's actually perfectly fine syntax. If your `__init__` method looks like this, it runs without error:

```
    def __init__(self, directory: str) -> None:
        """
        The files_summary attribute stores the summarized data for each Python file in the specified directory.
        """
        self.directory: str = os.listdir(directory) #Directory to be scanned

        [cls, funccount, codelines, characters] = self.analyze_files()

        self.files_summary: Dict[str, Dict[str, int]] = {
            dir: {
                'Number of Classes': cls,
                'Number of Functions': funccount,
                'Number of Lines of Code': codelines,
                'Number of Characters': characters
            }
        }
```

There are a number of issues, however. First, in the above method, you're using the variable name `dir`, but there is no such variable in scope. Unfortunately, `dir` is also the name of a Python built-in function. If you insert a `breakpoint()` after this section of code and print the value of `self.files_summary`, you'll see it looks something like this:

```
{<built-in function dir>: {'Number of Classes': 0, 'Number of Functions': 0, 'Number of Lines of Code': 0, 'Number of Characters': 0}}
```

In general, never pick variable names that shadow Python built-ins, because it can cause unexpected and hard to debug problems. If you use a decent editor with Python syntax highlighting support you will see these built-ins called out so that you can avoid this mistake.

I *think* rather than `dir` you mean `self.directory` (or just `directory`, because that variable is in scope at this point).

---

But there another problem.

In your `pretty_print` method, you are attempting to *call* `self.files_summary`, like this:

```
for cls, funccount, codelines, characters in self.files_summary():
```

But `self.files_summary` isn't a function and is not callable. It is a dictionary, which also means it doesn't really make sense to use it in a `for` loop like this. It's only ever going to have a single key due to the way you set it in `__init__`.

If I were you, I would break this program down in individual pieces, and get each piece working correctly first before trying to tie it all together. Make good use of both the interactive Python prompt and the debugger; using `breakpoint()` statements in your code to investigate the content of variables before you use them.

---

If I were to rewrite your code, I might do something like this:

```
import os
import re

from prettytable import PrettyTable

re_class = re.compile(r'class')
re_def = re.compile(r'\s*def')


class FileAnalyzer:
    def __init__(self, path: str) -> None:
        self.path = path
        self.analyze_files()

    def analyze_files(self) -> None:
        self.files = []

        for entry in os.listdir(self.path):
            if not entry.endswith('.py'):
                continue

            with open(entry, "r") as pyfile:

                cls = 0
                funccount = 0
                codelines = 0
                characters = 0

                for line in pyfile:
                    codelines += 1
                    characters += len(line)

                    if re_class.match(line):
                        cls += 1
                    elif re_def.match(line):
                        funccount += 1

            self.files.append((entry, cls, funccount, codelines, characters))

    def pretty_print(self) -> None:
        pt: PrettyTable = PrettyTable(
            field_names=['Filename',
                         '# of Classes', '# of Functions',
                         '# Lines of Code (Excluding Comments)',
                         '# of characters in file (Including Comments)'])

        for path, cls, funccount, codelines, characters in self.files:
            pt.add_row([path, cls, funccount, codelines, characters])

        print(pt)


x = FileAnalyzer('.')
x.pretty_print()
```

Note that I've dropped the multuple `for` loops in your `analyze_files` function; there's no reason to iterate through each file multiple times. This builds up an instance variable named `files` that is a list of results. The `pretty_print` method simply iterates over this list.

If I run the above code in my Python scratch directory, I get:

```
+--------------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
|         Filename         | # of Classes | # of Functions | # Lines of Code (Excluding Comments) | # of characters in file (Including Comments) |
+--------------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
|       yamltest.py        |      0       |       0        |                  30                  |                     605                      |
|       analyzer.py        |      1       |       3        |                  53                  |                     1467                     |
|         quake.py         |      0       |       0        |                  37                  |                     1035                     |
| test_compute_examples.py |      1       |       1        |                  10                  |                     264                      |
|   compute_examples.py    |      1       |       1        |                  4                   |                      82                      |
+--------------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: `dir` was meant to reference any particular file of interest in the directory (in this case, Python files). I've changed it to `for direct in self.directory` for now, but of course `direct: {` in `__init__` now returns `NameError: name 'direct' is not defined`

Comment: Right, that's the same problem we discussed in the comments: there is no variable named `direct` defined in that method. You have to define variables before you use them.

Comment: The idea would be to create an instance of each file's info and store it in the dictionary within `self.files_summary`. What would be the most optimal way to retrieve the values within the dictionary to use in `pretty_print` if I would not be able to call it like a function?

Comment: I've made some updates to the answer that might help out.